# PHP: how to create a "tree" of constants

Tags: php, abstract-class, constants

I wonder if it is possible in PHP to create a "tree" of constants (without instantiating a tree of classes) ... let me explain what I would like to do (code is not correct) :

```
abstract class logType {
   const Project = 1;
   const User = 2;
}
abstract class dbConstants {
   const logType = logType;
}
```

So that I use below in my code :

```
dbConstants::logType::Project
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use scalar data (integer, boolean, float and string), with PHP >5.6 you could also use scalar expressions, arrays and resources as the value of a constant as described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php). With an array structure you could do something like this then:

```php
abstract class logType
{
    const PROJECT = 1;
    const USER = 2;
}

abstract class dbConstants
{
    const logType = [
        logType::PROJECT,
        logType::USER
    ];
}

echo dbConstants::logType[logType::PROJECT];
```

Another approach would be to use a `trait` with `public static` members like this, if you do not want the class inheritances and reuse your code:

```php
trait logType
{
    public static $PROJECT = 1;
    public static $USER = 2;
}

abstract class dbConstants
{
    use logType;
}

echo dbConstants::$PROJECT;
```

Another way without the use of an array:

```
class logType
{
    const PROJECT = 1;
    const USER = 2;
}

abstract class dbConstants
{
    public static $logType;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logType = new logType();
    }
}

echo dbConstants::$logType::PROJECT;
```

Answer (score 0):

In php 7:

`define('animals', [
      'dog',
      'cat',
      'bird'
   ]);`

This will define a constant array.

In PHP 5.6 you can use `const` to declare a constant array.

Both of these can contain more arrays to form a structure.